# How repair damage from suction bath mat in tub

Tags: bathroom, shower, paint, bathtub, finish

My roommate went to clean our bathtub, so they took off the suction shower mat to do so. When they did, it messed with the finish on the tub. Some of it is now perforated and peeling. How do I repair this? The shower is wet in the pictures from previous use, the mat wasn’t retaining water. Thanks
[image: the bath mat]

[image: the bath mat again]

[image: the suction cup marks]

[[image: the peeling][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAQu7.jpg)

Comment: Don't think you would happy with DIY solution.  There are bathtub refinishing companies, unknown if they are permanent or good.  Maybe someone else can say.  Type of bathtub and finish on it are important to know.

Comment: The bath mats with suckers and the glued on stickers are known to cause damage and or mold.

Comment: That should not happen with a cast iron tub. The only way that would happen to a cast iron tub is if the prep was not done properly before refinishing, the finish would not adhere properly. Even if it was a "plastic" tub, that would not happen as the color goes all the way through.

Comment: Yup, this is a symptom of a crummy refinishing job. (I've never actually met a good refinishing job, fwiw.) It wasn't the fault of the mat at all.

Comment: It’s definitely not cast iron fwiw

Comment: the damage is not from removing the mat ... the damage is from stepping on the mat ... when you step on the mat, it moves around and grinds down on the tub finish

Comment: you can't fix that aside from re-refinishing the whole tub, like your chincy landlord did before you moved in.